# Is a subgraph either a spanning subgraph or a full subgraph?

Tags: graphs

> A graph $G' = (N' ,A')$ is a **spanning subgraph** of a graph $G = (N, A)$
> iff $N ' = N$ and $A' \subseteq A$.
>
> A graph $G' = (N',A')$ is a **full subgraph** of a
> graph $G = (N, A)$ iff $N' \subseteq N$ and $A' = \{(x,y) \in A \mid x,y \in N '\}$.

- I have to prove that *"If $G'$ is a subgraph of a graph $G$, then either
  G' is a spanning subgraph of $G$, or $G'$ is a full subgraph of $G$. If this statement
  is valid, provide a proof that it is valid, otherwise provide a counterexample"* but isn't a full subgraph actually a spanning subgraph?

I mean that any subgraph of $G$ is a full subgraph in the end, right?
Any ideas how I can prove the statement?

- My second question is how to calculate the number of spanning subgraphs of $G$ as a function of the number of nodes in $N$. How can I do this without knowing $A$ or how many edges I have in the graph?

Comment: Also, it might be good to write what do you mean by subgraph. because in the usual sense: $(N',A')$ is a subgraph of $(N,A)$ when $N' \subseteq N$ and $A' \subseteq A$. If this is the case, then what you called 'full subgraph' is not actually a 'subgraph' in the usual sense because it can have edges not present in the original graph.

Comment: @Billiska yes, it reflects what I meant .   

Actually the full subgraph will be a subgraph of G because I said that (x,y) ∈ A (which means from any pair of edges in the original graph - A ) I cannot add any new edges because then the pair won't belong to A.

And a subgraph G'=(N',A') is a graph of G=(N,A) where N′⊆N and A'⊆A

Comment: You're right about that. then, I am undeleting my answer. it should be valid now.

Comment: I suggest you make the question more focused. If you have multiple questions, it is better to make multiple questions.

Answer (score 2):

On your question "isn't a full subgraph actually a spanning subgraph?". The answer is no, a full subgraph doesn't need to be a spanning subgraph. By your definition, a full subgraph can have lesser number of vertices than in the original graph. However, a spanning subgraph must have exactly the same set of vertices in the original graph.

On your second question "how to calculate the number of spanning subgraphs of $G$ as a function of number of nodes in $N$." Since it is a **fact** that graph $G = (N,A)$ with differing $A$ will have differing number of possible spanning subgraphs, I suspect you might have misunderstood the question. For example, does the question actually only ask for **an upper bound** of the number of possible spanning subgraphs as function of $|N|$?